# Azure Query - List snapshots where name contains AzureBackup_ and must have a tag "CreatedBy : AzureBackup" , But must have any other tag

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I need azure query to list snapshots with following conditions:

1. name of snapshot contains word "AzureBackup_"
2. Must have a tag & value "CreatedBy : AzureBackup"
3. Must not have any opther tag except the one mentioned in point no 2.

I tried many thinggs like:

`az snapshot list --query "[?contains(name, 'AzureBackup') && tags.CreatedBy == 'AzureBackup' && length(tags) == 1].[id]" --output tsv`

But getting error

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Query - List snapshots where the name contains AzureBackup_ and must have the tag “CreatedBy : AzureBackup” , But must have any other tag

I have created a snapshot with the below **name** and **tags**.

**Name:** AzureBackup
**Tags:** CreatedBy: AzureBackup

[image]

> I have referred the the below commands from this [MS
>
> document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/snapshot?view=azure-cli-latest#az-snapshot-list)  to retrieve the **Snapshot** if the tags match.
>
> ```bash
> $snap= az snapshot list --query
> "[?tags.CreatedBy=='AzureBackup'].name"
> ```

The above command filters snapshots by the **CreatedBy** tag with a value of **AzureBackup** and selects only the **name** field of the snapshots.

**Output:**

[image]

> ```
>  $snapshot = az snapshot list --query
> "[?tags.CreatedBy=='AzureBackup' && contains(name, 'AzureBackup')]"
> ```

> Above command referred from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/snapshot?view=azure-cli-latest#az-snapshot-list)

The above command filters snapshots by the **CreatedBy** tag with a value of **AzureBackup** and selects all fields of the snapshots that have `'AzureBackup'` in their name.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: But my requirement is "Must not have any other tag except the one mentioned in point no 2."

Comment: Yes, You can use same command to check Snapshot if tags are match (tags.CreatedBy=='AzureBackup').